# react-native setState resetting navigation

Tags: react-native

I'm using the [react-native-material-bottom-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-bottom-navigation) package for my app.  But whenever I call `setState`, even if I don't even pass a new state change, the bottom navigation resets to the first tab. What is causing this? The example code works just fine but as soon as I throw in `setState` it messes up.

Example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import BottomNavigation, { Tab } from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        labelColor="white"
        rippleColor="white"
        style={{ height: 56, elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0 }}
        onTabChange={(newTabIndex) => alert(`New Tab at position ${newTabIndex}`)}
      >
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#37474F"
          label="Movies & TV"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="tv" />}
        />
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#00796B"
          label="Music"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="music-note" />}
        />
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#5D4037"
          label="Books"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="book" />}
        />
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#3E2723"
          label="Newsstand"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="newspaper" />}
        />
      </BottomNavigation>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `this.setState()` in a React Component, it will re-render itself. This means that `BottomNavigation` will be reset to its default state, **if you don't tell it which state it should show.**

The default state of the Bottom Navigation is to set the first Tab to active.

## Solution

You can define the state of the Bottom Navigation using the `activeTab` prop.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = { activeTab: 0 }

  handleTabChange = (newTabIndex) => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: newTabIndex })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
        onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
      >
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#37474F"
          label="Movies & TV"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="tv" />}
        />
        {/* Skipped Tabs for brevity */}
      </BottomNavigation>
    )
  }
}
```

This will keep the Bottom Navigation in its current state even after a re-render.

An example can also be found in [react-native-material-bottom-navigation/examples](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation/blob/7961136dfe628f5de407a6287b5e8c8d8b420442/examples/StatefulBottomNavigation.js).